# How Hide private dedicated server at home

Tags: ip, dedicated-server

I installed a dedicated server at home which works fine. I host several services like mysql, apache, websocket, etc... The problem: people who go to my website will know my personal ip address. I hidded my ip under a type A DNS but there is no problem for people to get my real ip.
So how can i fully hide my ip address. Are there some services that provide this? Proxy? Vpn?

Comment: You have a personal home server. If you want to acces from outside, do you have DynamicDNS redirection provided by (eg.) DynDNS et relayed by your internet box?

Comment: I don't need a DynDNS because I have a fixed ip address. I don't think dynDNS help to hide my ip address to others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky question. You cannot truly hide the public-facing IP address of a server if you intend it to be accessed by the public, because they need the IP to route to you.

- If you use a public proxy, that proxy will have to know your real IP.
- If you use a private proxy, then anyone who wants to visit your site will need to know the IP address of the proxy server, which is probably also owned by you.
- If you expose all the services only on the internal network, then you can VPN into your home network to get your services, but then nobody else be able to use your services. Also, the VPN server's IP address will need to be public to anyone you want to give access to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 1. I dont want a public proxy (I guess). 2. No problem if the proxy can has his own IP address. Has it? 3. No I want people to access my services. Anyway, is there online services that provide the rent of an IP Address? Is the proxy this kind of service?

Comment: @AntoineLafarge, I have not heard of a way to rent an IP address specifically, although there are many things I have not heard of. However, you can rent a Virtual Private Server from an organization like DigitalOcean, and run a proxy on that. The proxy would functionally be a web server, except it would forward all requests to your home server, fetch responses back, and then return them to the user.

Comment: Thank you Merlin, I think this solution would be a great for me. Are the proxy and the VPS both useful for me? And is this system working with any network protocols? I mean TCP, UDP and over protocols (HTTP, websockets, SSH, SSL, SFTP...)